# Compilation fails on using Generics?

Tags: java, generics

I wrote the following code which works absolutely fine. The problem is when I change the class from `A` to Generics `A<T>` then it fails to compile.

```
public class A {
    class B {
    }

    static void m(B i) {
    }

    static class C extends B {
        C() {
            new A().super();
        }

    }
}
```

When i change `A` to `A<T>` compilation fails with following error on `B`.

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type B

```
public class A<T> {
    class B {
    }

    static void m(B i) {
    }

    static class C extends B {
        C() {
            new A().super();
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it working fine in the first case and failing in the second?

Comment: Because in the second, you have an inner class that only belongs to a parent of a specific type.

Comment: But again subclass only extends to generics inner class, If you look closer to compilation error it says some thing different.

Answer (score 6):

In the generic case, when you refer to `B`, you are really referring to an instance of `A<T>.B`.

Unless you have an enclosing instance of `A<T>`, you are effectively trying to enclose a raw reference to an `A`. That's not allowed, because `B` wants to refer to the type variable associated with its enclosing instance, which doesn't exist.

In the non-generic case, there's no type variable, so `B` isn't trying to refer to something which doesn't exist.

The simplest solution is to add the `A<T>` explicitly, e.g.

```
static void m(A<?>.B obj)
```

or

```
static <T> void m(A<T>.B obj)
```

and

```
static class C<T> extends A<T>.B {
    C() {
        new A<T>().super();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ShowStopper it's the same explanation as [the last time you posted the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676895/compilation-error-while-using-generics/43676915?noredirect=1#comment74400291_43676915).

Comment: No last time you said , it will break for concrete class as well that is why i pasted screen shots..this time.. :)

Comment: @ShowStopper I copy+pasted my previous answer.

Comment: it should be my mistake then, Sorry for the inconvenience caused.